# Minikube ingress is not responding

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to redirect traffic to my Cluster Deployment object. My Deployment object is a node image which depends on a SQL server image.

```
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: example-ingress
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  spec:
    rules:
    - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: simptekapi-api-service
          servicePort: 5000
```

MY Cluster IP service ====>

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: simptekapi-api-service
spec:
  selector:
    component: api
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

My deployment Object ===>

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: simptekapi-api-deployment
spec:
    replicas: 3
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            component: api
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                component: api
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: simptekapi-api
                  image: nayan2/simptekapi
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 5000
```

My node image is basically a Test API Project. I am sharing the SignIn url (http://Minikube_ip/api/v1/auth/SignIn)

Seems like everything ok to me. As am still literally a newbie with Kubernetes. It's hard for me to figure out what I am doing wrong.

While I have tried to reach my pods through Node-Port, everything was perfect. I don't know why I am unable to react it out through ingress.

[image]

kubectl get ingress example-ingress ==> Result

[image]

AND kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx ==> Result

[image]

Comment: share output of kubectl get ingress example-ingress and logs from ingress controller pod

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu PLease check again. I have updated the question section.

Comment: Have u referred this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu can your help me with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`. Do I need to keep it to my YAML file as `/api/v1/` my base path for my API

Comment: @Amjad Do you still require help with this?

Comment: @OhHiMark, thanks man for asking, No, I have solved the problem.

Comment: You forgot to use capture groups in your rewrite annotation. See the examples [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#create-an-ingress-resource). As said by Arghya, have you familiarized yourself with the second link?

Comment: @OhHiMark are you indicating to `/$1` or `/$2` in URL rewrite rule?

Comment: @Amjad [Yes](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target)

Comment: @OhHiMark I don't think so, The Url rewrite rule is not necessary for me, As I am not rewriting anything. Why should I use that?

Comment: The comment section should not be used as a chat. To avoid further confusion please provide the info you were asked for by editing the question: 1. Logs from ingress controller pod; 2. Have you tried to follow the guide from the official docs? This is essential here because we need to know what went wrong by checking the logs and we also need you to understand the whole process.